# Big Data Analytics Using Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, bigdata

How can I fix this error? I get an error on executing the last cell,
where did I make a mistake?
does it have anything with my program version? or something similar?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/St5nJ.png)

```
def count_examples(Data):
count = Data.map(lambda labelPoint: (labelPoint.label,1)).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y)
return count.collect()

counts = count_examples(Data)

counts3 = count_examples(sc.parallelize(Data.take(3)))

assert type(counts3) == list, 'Incorrect return type'
assert type(counts3[0]) == tuple, 'Incorrect return type'
assert type(counts3[0][0]) == float, 'Incorrect return type'
assert type(counts3[0][1]) == int, 'Incorrect return type'

assert counts3[0][0] == 5.0, 'Incorrect return value'
assert counts3[0][1] == 2, 'Incorrect return value'

AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-9c21c32429c5> in <module>()
----> 1 assert counts3[0][0] == 5.0, 'Incorrect return value'
      2 assert counts3[0][1] == 2, 'Incorrect return value'

AssertionError: Incorrect return value
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not an error but an assertion failure.
Basically, what is happening here is that the value stored in `counts3[0][0]` does not equal 5.0

You can easily fix this in two steps

1. know what the expected value is
   to so so simply change your code to

   ```
   assert counts3[0][0] == 5.0, f"Incorrect return value, actual is {counts3[0][0]}"
   ```

When you run this code it will fail again but will output the exact expected value

2. change the value in assertion to expected value from the above step

Comment: you are right ==2.0 not 5.0, but unfortunately, I can't change that cell.
is there any other solution?

Comment: @HawarDizayee, unfortunately the only other option would be to change the input data so that  ```counts3[0][0]``` equals ```5.0```. otherwise you will have to get rid of the assert statement